# Migrating smartphone app to different domain

Tags: android, ios, phonegap

Supposing there's a smartphone app with hardcoded API endpoints, how could I go about pointing it to a different domain without requiring all users to update?

I've thought about redirecting all network calls to the old domain to the new one while logging them so I can "deprecate" it when the right time comes in a few months/years, but I'm wondering whether that would have some kind of overhead / there's some better way out there.

Also, in the future, how would I go about avoiding this kind of problem? Should I have some kind of central server that hands out the settings to use when the app starts up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a webserver acting like load balancer responding for the actual domain and the new domain